# How to display caps lock status in Cinnamon's system tray?

Tags: debian, notification-area, cinnamon, capslock

In the system settings menu (under Applets) I have found BetterLock, but it doesn't work. Can this be fixed or is there another way to display caps lock status in the system tray?

Answer (score 0):

For BetterLock, the default install from the [Cinnamon Spices website](http://cinnamon-spices.linuxmint.com/applets/view/83) should work (see instructions on top of [this page](http://cinnamon-spices.linuxmint.com/applets)). Using Debian Stretch (currently 'testing'), the installation from the system menus will fail. To fix it, go to `~/.local/share/cinnamon/applets` and rename the `betterlock` folder to `betterlock@entelechy`. Adding it to the panel should work now.

TL;DR: BetterLock can be fixed using this command:

```
mv ~/.local/share/cinnamon/applets/betterlock{,@entelechy}
```